# if else condition for checking 3 statements

Tags: php, if-statement

Here is my code for checking the id.I want to check the sesion id is 1or 2 or 3.If it is 1 then corresponding query fetches the datas from db and execute.But here i got query was empty.

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['id'] =='1')
{
$sql ="select a.`id` 'User ID', a.`username` 'Username',MAX(b.login_timestamp) 'Last Logged',count(*) 'Total No. of logins for the Month', count(*)/30 'Avg no. of Logins /day'  from users a left join `client_access_log` b  on b.unique_id=a.unique_id  where b.`username` in( 'ghfh','sdd')  and 
`login_timestamp` between DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE) GROUP BY a.id order by count(*) desc";
}
elseif($_SESSION['id'] == '2')
{
$sql ="select a.`id` 'User ID', a.`username` 'Username',MAX(b.login_timestamp) 'Last Logged',count(*) 'Total No. of logins for the Month', count(*)/30 'Avg no. of Logins /day'  from users a left join `client_access_log` b  on b.unique_id=a.unique_id  where b.`username` in( 'dff')  and 
`login_timestamp` between DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE) GROUP BY a.id order by count(*) desc";
}
elseif($_SESSION['id'] == '3')
{
$sql ="select a.`id` 'User ID', a.`username` 'Username',MAX(b.login_timestamp) 'Last Logged',count(*) 'Total No. of logins for the Month', count(*)/30 'Avg no. of Logins /day'  from users a left join `client_access_log` b  on b.unique_id=a.unique_id  where b.`username` in( 'wededf')  and 
`login_timestamp` between DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE) GROUP BY a.id order by count(*) desc";
}
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(!$query)
    {
        mysql_close();
        echo json_encode("There was an error running the query: " . mysql_error());
    }
    elseif(mysql_num_rows($query)==0)
    {
        mysql_close();
        echo json_encode("No results returned");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $header = false;
        $output_string = "";
        $output_string .=  "<table border='2'>\n";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            if(!$header)
            {
                $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                foreach($row as $header => $value)
                {
                    $output_string .= "<th>{$header}</th>\n";
                }
                $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
            }
            $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
            foreach($row as $value)
            {
                $output_string .= "<th>{$value}</th>\n";
            }
            $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
        }
        $output_string .= "</table>\n";
    }
    mysql_close();
    echo json_encode($output_string);
        ?>
```

Comment: Have you started the session first..by `session_start();`

Comment: Try adding some debug information to verify all variables are correct. So start with something like `echo $_SESSION['id']` before the ifs and `echo $sql` after the ifs. That will probably tell you some more what went wrong.

Comment: Also, stop using `mysql`, it's deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

hey try by removing the '' from the comparision

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['id'] == 1)
{
$sql ="select a.`id` 'User ID', a.`username` 'Username',MAX(b.login_timestamp) 'Last Logged',count(*) 'Total No. of logins for the Month', count(*)/30 'Avg no. of Logins /day'  from users a left join `client_access_log` b  on b.unique_id=a.unique_id  where b.`username` in( 'ghfh','sdd')  and 
`login_timestamp` between DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE) GROUP BY a.id order by count(*) desc";
}
elseif ($_SESSION['id'] == 2)
{
$sql ="select a.`id` 'User ID', a.`username` 'Username',MAX(b.login_timestamp) 'Last Logged',count(*) 'Total No. of logins for the Month', count(*)/30 'Avg no. of Logins /day'  from users a left join `client_access_log` b  on b.unique_id=a.unique_id  where b.`username` in( 'dff')  and 
`login_timestamp` between DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE) GROUP BY a.id order by count(*) desc";
}
elseif ($_SESSION['id'] == 3)
{
$sql ="select a.`id` 'User ID', a.`username` 'Username',MAX(b.login_timestamp) 'Last Logged',count(*) 'Total No. of logins for the Month', count(*)/30 'Avg no. of Logins /day'  from users a left join `client_access_log` b  on b.unique_id=a.unique_id  where b.`username` in( 'wededf')  and 
`login_timestamp` between DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE) GROUP BY a.id order by count(*) desc";
}
```

and try to make some spaces between the keywords.